# Проверить первый символ в input на лету

Tags: jquery, input

В общем есть поле input куда вводиться номер телефона

Как сделать так, чтобы проверялось на лету, если введен первый символ "0", то автоматом добавлялось "38" к тому символу "0".

То есть пользователь вводит номер телефона 05 и тд, а ему сразу выбивает 3805 и тд
Через маску не надо. Именно таким образом надо

Comment: В `js`есть функция [charAt](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt) ей и проверяйте с использованием событий `keyboard`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой пример:
https://jsfiddle.net/9h73fek1/2/

```
<input type="text">
<script>
  var input = document.body.children[0];
  input.oninput = function() {
    if(input.value[0] == 0 && input.value != '')
    {
      input.value = 38 + input.value;
    }
  };
</script>
```

Comment: И в каком месте тут проверка первого символа, в упор не вижу? Как вы проверите если я вставлю туда `05` сразу?

Comment: @And Поправил, не подумал о вставке - извиняюсь. Вот проверка if(input.value[0] == 0 && input.value != '')

Comment: @And Почему так считаете? Любая строка это массив символов, и соответственно первый элемент этого массива это и есть первый символ. Проверено.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку, пригодилось ваше решение, и маленький, лаконичный код

Comment: @ВладимирТытыкалоб его можно сделать еще короче и лаконичнее без всяких `!=''` и т.д. без `function` и `input[0]` - массивов.

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(document).on('keydown', '#example', function(e) {
  if ($('#example').val().length == 0 && e.key == 0) {
    $('#example').val('38');
  }
  if ($('#example').val().length == 3 && e.keyCode == 8) {
    $('#example').val('');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="example"/>
```